# In Helm Kubernetes config, how can I share many environment vars between multiple deployment files

Tags: kubernetes, helm

We're using Helm to deploy our app to K8s. In 4 different deployment files (one for each service) and a job file for migrations, we have to have an identical set of `env` variables. Whenever we need to add a new one, we need to add it to all 5 files. Is there a way to share these so new env vars only need to be added once and all 5 files will pick them up (and also cannot ever be out of sync)?

Here's an example of a deployment file (with potentially sensitive values redacted).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}-celery
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}-celery
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "helm-chart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}-celery
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: worker-celery
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCountCelery }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}-celery
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}-celery
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}-celery
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}-celery
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.imagePullSecretsName }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-celery
          image: "{{ .Values.appImage.repository }}:{{ .Values.imageTag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.appImage.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["celery"]
          args: [REDACTED]
          env:
            - name: DJANGO_DEBUG
              value: "{{ .Values.djangoDebug }}"
            - name: DATABASE_NAME
              value: "{{ .Values.databaseName }}"
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: DATABASE_HOST
              value: "myapp-haproxy.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local"
            - name: MEMCACHED_HOST
              value: "myapp-memcached.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local"
            - name: SENDGRID_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: SENDGRID_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: OBJECT_STORE_ENDPOINT_URL
              value: [REDACTED]
            - name: OBJECT_STORE_REGION_NAME
              value: [REDACTED]
            - name: OBJECT_STORE_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: OBJECT_STORE_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: OBJECT_STORE_CDN_URL
              value: [REDACTED]
            - name: QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: QUICKBOOKS_ENVIRONMENT
              value: production
            - name: XERO_CONSUMER_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: XERO_CONSUMER_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: SAGE_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: SAGE_CLIENT_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: [REDACTED]
                  key: [REDACTED]
            - name: ACCOUNTANCY_REDIRECT_URI_PREFIX
              value: [REDACTED]
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.celeryResources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

I'm not sure if it adds any complications, but you can see that some are using variables from `values.yaml` (such as `{{ .Values.djangoDebug }}`), some are referring to Kubernetes secrets and some use the `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` variable.

Additionally, the indentation required is the same for the 4 `deployment` files but different for the `job` file.

I'm trying to share a bunch of `env` values but also be able to optionally add some extras to some files.

I hope that makes sense? And thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the thing you need is a `ConfigMap`.

> Many applications require configuration via some combination of config
>   files, command line arguments, and environment variables. These
>   configuration artifacts should be decoupled from image content in
>   order to keep containerized applications portable. The ConfigMap API
>   resource provides mechanisms to inject containers with configuration
>   data while keeping containers agnostic of Kubernetes. ConfigMap can be
>   used to store fine-grained information like individual properties or
>   coarse-grained information like entire config files or JSON blobs.

Basicly you create a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap)  and setup a proper `key:value`. After that you use the created `ConfigMap` to declare it's values as environment in your `Deployments`.

Here you can find the [official example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables):

---

Create a ConfigMap containing multiple key-value pairs.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  SPECIAL_LEVEL: very
  SPECIAL_TYPE: charm
```

Use `envFrom` to define all of the `ConfigMap’s` data as container environment variables. The key from the `ConfigMap` becomes the environment variable name in the Pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Now, the Pod’s output includes environment variables `SPECIAL_LEVEL=very` and `SPECIAL_TYPE=charm`

---

Adjust to your needs and please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I didn't realise you could use a `ConfigMap` in `envFrom`. Do you know how I can include the secret values in the `ConfigMap`?

Comment: There is a different purpose for ConfigMaps and Secrets. Take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79224). Especially [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79224#issuecomment-533942608) comment answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help.